# BindingNavigator delete item works but add item doesn't

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingnavigator

I have DataGridView, BindingNavigator and BindingSource...

Delete button works but add doesn't, how to debug this guys?

```
private void FillDataGrids()
    {
        formLoaded = false;
        voziloBindingSource.DataSource = r.DohvatiSvaVozila();
        djelatnikBindingSource.DataSource = r.DohvatiSveDjelatnike();
        formLoaded = true;
    }
```

I don't know what code to post, because everything else is set up through properties... I already have one DataGridView ("djelatnik") set up with bindingnavigator and the 2 functionalities work fine (add/delete)

Comment: Post a proper answer, so that this question can be closed out accordingly. Don't include an answer in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my BindingNavigator's AddNewItem property was set wrong.

Once I set it to default name everything worked fine